# Cast exception using RestAssured/Apache http client config

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, rest-assured

I have this code that I'm trying to rewrite due to deprecation of CoreConnectionPNames:

```
RestAssuredConfig config = RestAssured.config()
                .httpClient(HttpClientConfig.httpClientConfig()
                        .setParam(CoreConnectionPNames.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, TIMEOUT * 1000)
                        .setParam(CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT, TIMEOUT * 1000));

        return RestAssured.given().proxy("http://someurl:port").config(config).relaxedHTTPSValidation();
```

I have the following:

```
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.config.HttpClientConfig;
import io.restassured.config.RestAssuredConfig;
import io.restassured.specification.RequestSpecification;
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.params.CoreConnectionPNames;

public class RequestFactory {

    private static final int TIMEOUT = 10;

    public static RequestSpecification create() {

        HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("http://someurl:port");

        RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
                .setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT * 1000)
                .setConnectionRequestTimeout(TIMEOUT * 1000)
                .setSocketTimeout(TIMEOUT * 1000)
                .setProxy(proxy)
                .build();

        HttpClientConfig httpClientFactory = HttpClientConfig.httpClientConfig()
                .httpClientFactory(() -> HttpClientBuilder.create()
                        .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
                        .build());

        RestAssured.config=RestAssured.config().httpClient(httpClientFactory);

        return RestAssured.given().config(RestAssured.config).relaxedHTTPSValidation();
    }

}
```

That I thought looked ok, though wasn't sure whether to put proxy in the custom config or factory, but when I run the code:

```
RequestSpecification httpRequest = RequestFactory.create();
Response response = httpRequest.get(urlToTest);
```

I get the following. Is my code ok and it's just a dependency/version thing or is simply I've done it wrong. Either way, is there a way to fix this.

I was given a choice of importing apache http core 4 or 5 and chose 4 as 5 was giving too many errors.

```
null: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: 
Cannot cast object 'org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient@2cec704c' 
with class 'org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient' 
to class 'org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient'
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.continueCastOnSAM(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.continueCastOnNumber(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:329)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.castToType(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:243)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.castToType(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:615)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1654)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1268)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1035)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:819)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObject.invokeMethod(GroovyObject.java:39)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:55)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:171)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:203)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1661)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1268)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1035)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:819)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObject.invokeMethod(GroovyObject.java:39)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:55)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:171)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:203)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.get(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:171)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.get(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
    at com.bt.qa.ccta.servicenow.stepDefns.RestSteps.iCurlComponent(RestSteps.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at io.cucumber.java.Invoker.doInvoke(Invoker.java:66)
    at io.cucumber.java.Invoker.invoke(Invoker.java:24)
    at io.cucumber.java.AbstractGlueDefinition.invokeMethod(AbstractGlueDefinition.java:47)
    at io.cucumber.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:29)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.CoreStepDefinition.execute(CoreStepDefinition.java:66)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.PickleStepDefinitionMatch.runStep(PickleStepDefinitionMatch.java:63)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.ExecutionMode$1.execute(ExecutionMode.java:10)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestStep.executeStep(TestStep.java:92)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestStep.run(TestStep.java:64)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.PickleStepTestStep.run(PickleStepTestStep.java:51)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:104)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:71)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.lambda$execute$5(Runtime.java:110)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.runTestCase(CucumberExecutionContext.java:117)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.lambda$execute$6(Runtime.java:110)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(Runtime.java:233)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.lambda$run$2(Runtime.java:86)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.stream.SliceOps$1$1.accept(SliceOps.java:204)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.tryAdvance(ArrayList.java:1361)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:486)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:566)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:87)
    at io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.run(Main.java:92)
    at io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.main(Main.java:34)
```

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, did you find the solution?

Comment: Unfurtunately it's an known issue: https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/issues/497